# Boost Managed Mapped File std::unordered_map Linux Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, boost, segmentation-fault, unordered-map, interprocess

I am trying to map an std::unordered_map with boost interproccess.
With Windows everything works fine. On Linux i get a segmentation fault.

```
    using namespace boost::interprocess;

    struct State {
        uint8_t state = 0;

        State(uint8_t _state) {
            state = _state;
        }
    };

    managed_mapped_file file(open_or_create, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

    typedef uint32_t KeyType;
    typedef State  MappedType;
    typedef std::pair<const KeyType, MappedType> ValueType;
    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<ValueType, boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager> UnorderedMapAllocator;
    typedef boost::unordered_map<KeyType, MappedType, boost::hash<KeyType>, std::equal_to<KeyType>, UnorderedMapAllocator> unordered_map;

    unordered_map* map = file.find_or_construct<unordered_map>("fault_states")(3, boost::hash<KeyType>(), std::equal_to<KeyType>(), file.get_segment_manager());

    uint32_t size = (uint32_t)map->size();
    for (uint32_t i = size; i < size + 100; ++i) {
        State state(46);
        map->insert(ValueType(i, state));
    }

    for (auto x : *map) {
        std::cout << x.first << " ";
        std::cout << x.second.state << std::endl;
    }
```

On the first run everything works fine. On the second run i get the segmentation fault.
If i use boost::unordered_map instead everything works fine, but i have to use the std version

Boost Version 1.6.4
Gcc Version 7.4.0

Comment: I can reproduce this with a more "hardened" source, and boost 1.70 as well. I think it is likely a bug in `std::unordered_map` where the allocator is not being honoured, or it depends on some unspecified implementation details that it shouldn't.

Comment: Here's my reproducer in case it helps you: [using GNU stdlib](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cc04f201dc43ada) and [using boost](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ea66f05367be6f3). Note the difference is only one single `std` -> `boost` in the code now.

Comment: Thank you. Then i have to use the boost unordered map for now